Migrating Azure Notification hub from Using GCM to FCM using rest API call
My company used NotificationHub to send push notification to one of our App which is controlled by Firebase console. Recently firebase is deprecating the their GCM legacy endpoint and want to move to FCMV1 endpoint by June 20th. So our current app need to be updated in backend but i have seen that azure notification Hub has Rest API support also, So i am trying to look for Docs but i didnt get much useful one.
curl --location 'https://{ourNotificationHub}.servicebus.windows.net/{customHubName}/registrations' \ --header 'Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=https%3a%2f%2fNotificationHub-test%2fhubNaem&sig=7OHJXs6wcK4CXELfl72tt4DleNtAfSCleytGeLR6RY%3D&se=1714863748&skn=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ --data '{ "registrationId": "4qX-Od8lS0yKvX8V7ITP7X:APA91bH8qOTNvMNNFI6fljFb6iI_KgSRqIuYldu8zNPK1n-Kn-xrgy2HlKdCwUsUK8yROxBifDzMgwpYkwIdZQl-YX0_R_HhyODwKGF65lqluFIhZ9V9Orq5k6oDnN1gZXfyd5WjcKf_", "platform": "fcmV1", "tags": ["PAIR-ID_5271"] }'
But it didnt work can you please point me to right documentation I am looking for JSON supported request i found XML one but want JSON datatype docs for Registering a device, Sending the notification to device, updating registration, deleting registration can you please provide some example with working code would help
Thanks in advance
I have tried with XML it has registered. But when i send the message it failed with registartionId


Recently firebase is deprecating the their GCM legacy endpoint and want to move to FCMV1 endpoint by June 20th.



Yes, you'll need to update your backend code to use the new API endpoint and authentication method.

To register a device using JSON, you’ll need to make an HTTP POST request to the appropriate endpoint. Create a registration for an FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) device using the Azure Notification Hubs REST API:
curl --location 'https://{yourNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{yourHubName}/messages' \
     --header 'Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=https%3a%2f%2f{yourNamespace}%2f{yourHubName}&sig=yourSasToken&se=1714863748&skn=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature' \
     --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     --data '{
         "data": {
             "message": "Hello from Azure Notification Hubs!"
         },
         "target": {
             "tag": "PAIR-ID_5271"
         }
     }'


Create a registration for an FCM device using Node.js and the axios library.

Code:
const axios = require('axios');

const namespace = '{yourNamespace}';
const hubName = '{yourHubName}';
const sharedAccessSignature = 'yourSharedAccessSignature'; // Replace with your actual SAS token

const registrationData = {
    registrationId: '4qX-Od8lS0yKvX8V7ITP7X:APA91bH8qOTNvMNNFI6fljFb6iI_KgSRqIuYldu8zNPK1n-Kn-xrgy2HlKdCwUsUK8yROxBifDzMgwpYkwIdZQl-YX0_R_HhyODwKGF65lqluFIhZ9V9Orq5k6oDnN1gZXfyd5WjcKf_',
    platform: 'fcmV1',
    tags: ['PAIR-ID_5271']
};

axios.post(`https://${namespace}.servicebus.windows.net/${hubName}/registrations`,
    registrationData,
    {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `SharedAccessSignature sr=https%3a%2f%2f${namespace}%2f${hubName}&sig=${sharedAccessSignature}&se=1714863748&skn=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log('Device registered successfully:', response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error registering device:', error.message);
    });

Reference:

logicappsio/NotificationHubAPI: Azure Notification Hub API

Notification Hubs REST APIs


Output:
Registering a Device
Successful Response.
{
    "registrationId": "4qX-Od8lS0yKvX8V7ITP7X:APA91bH8qOTNvMNNFI6fljFb6iI_KgSRqIuYldu8zNPK1n-Kn-xrgy2HlKdCwUsUK8yROxBifDzMgwpYkwIdZQl-YX0_R_HhyODwKGF65lqluFIhZ9V9Orq5k6oDnN1gZXfyd5WjcKf_",
    "gcmRegistrationId": "APA91bH8qOTNvMNNFI6fljFb6iI_KgSRqIuYldu8zNPK1n-Kn-xrgy2HlKdCwUsUK8yROxBifDzMgwpYkwIdZQl-YX0_R_HhyODwKGF65lqluFIhZ9V9Orq5k6oDnN1gZXfyd5WjcKf_",
    "platform": "fcm",
    "tags": ["PAIR-ID_5271"],
    "expirationTime": "2024-06-20T00:00:00Z",
    "location": "https://testmay028.servicebus.windows.net/testhubmay38/registrations/4qX-Od8lS0yKvX8V7ITP7X:APA91bH8qOTNvMNNFI6fljFb6iI_KgSRqIuYldu8zNPK1n-Kn-xrgy2HlKdCwUsUK8yROxBifDzMgwpYkwIdZQl-YX0_R_HhyODwKGF65lqluFIhZ9V9Orq5k6oDnN1gZXfyd5WjcKf_"
}

Sending a Notification
Successful Response:
{
    "trackingId": "12345abcd-6789-efgh-ijkl-67890mnopqrst",
    "state": "Scheduled",
    "notificationId": "abcd1234-5678-efgh-ijkl-12345678mnop"
}

